# How to derive the population covariance matrix for multiple regression?

Tags: multiple-regression, structural-equation-modeling

Assume $Y = \gamma_{11}X_{1} + \gamma_{12}X_{2}+\zeta_{1}$, and $Cov(X_{2}, X_{1})=\phi_{21}$

The population covariance can be represented as:

$
\sum = \begin{bmatrix}
V(Y) & & \\
Cov(X_{1}, Y) & V(X_{1}) & \\
Cov(X_{2}, Y) & Cov(X_{2}, X_{1}) & V(X_{2})
\end{bmatrix}
$

How to derive all the elements in the population covariance matrix and get $\sum\theta$?

Comment: To what does "$\theta$" refer?  You don't supply enough information to compute $\Sigma:$ you also need to know the variances of the $X_i,$ the variance of $\zeta_1,$ and the covariance of $\zeta_1$ with each of the $X_i.$ Once you have those, simply use the basic bilinearity of covariance to calculate the entries.

Comment: From the tag and the symbols you have used, it appears that you are talking about structural equation models, but your question asks about regression.

Comment: We'd also need to know the variance of X1 and the variance of X2. (That is, the whole of the theta matrix).